# Switch keyboard layouts from Tcl/Tk program

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

Is there existing a way to switch keyboard layouts from inside of my Tcl/Tk program?
Several years ago I implemented separate shared library through which I did it. But I've lost that code and now try to find a more easy way.

Link to ready to use Windows 8 dll is also acceptable.

Comment: There's no core Tk functionality to do this, and I don't know of any extension that does it (unless it is hidden away inside TWAPI).

Comment: By your advice I looked onto TWAPI. It does allow necessary switch by sending key pressing sequence. It is acceptable solution in certain limits. The only drawback is I unable to determine which language is the current one. And thus no ability to know for sure must be language swithched or not. Anyway, thanks for tip.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is nothing built into tcl/tk to do that. You'll likely need to find a platform-specific tool, and call it via exec.